# using ios device as a menu to run video on remote computer?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I want to use my ipad app as a menu to play videos stored on a server , those videos will run on a computer not on my ipad.
i dont use the apple tv because the customer dont want that the menu (ipad app) shows on the diffusion screen.

What is the best approach to do that job ?

Comment: Your question is too broad, but your general approach will be to establish some sort of communication between your iOS app and the program running on the computer, probably using a network connection

Comment: yes, there is network connection, but what am lookin for the server side aproach, some kind of listener to play instantaly the video posted from the ios app (id)